# SSE2 Color Blending

Tags: gcc, x86, clang, sse, intrinsics

I've a code doing a simple color blending:

```
  dr = (((dr-sr)*sa)>>8) + sr;
  dg = (((dg-sg)*sa)>>8) + sg;
  db = (((db-sb)*sa)>>8) + sb;
```

Where `sr,sg,sb` are source color, `sa` is source alpha, `dr,dg,db` is the color already in frame buffer.

Now obviously this code is the single biggest bottleneck, because it is done for millions of pixels, so I tried to optimize it using GCC/Clang's SSE intrinsics:

```
__m128 srgb = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_setr_epi32(sb,sg,sr,0));
__m128 drgb = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_set1_epi32(dst_rgb),imask));
__m128 msa = _mm_set1_ps((float)sa*(1.0f/255.0f));
__m128 r1 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(_mm_sub_ps(drgb,srgb), msa), srgb);
__m128 r2 = _mm_cvtps_epi32(r1);
dst_rgb = _mm_extract_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi8(r2,omask),0);
```

I had to use floats, because GCC's SSE intrinsics don't appear to have proper int32 multiply to do the `color * sa`. I also cant really use _mm_set1_epi32(src_rgb) and source color in XMM registers, because sr,sg,sb are passed through several lookup tables, before blending. AVX2 does support lookup tables with gather operations, but SSE2 doesn't appear to.

Unfortunately it only slowed down the code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or SSE's FPU just can't compete with integer operators? Maybe I should use MMX, or MMX is even slower on modern CPUs? I've -march=native -O3 -ffast-math options turned on.

@harold suggested doing full integer SIMD version, but it is still slower than non-SSE:

```
static uint8_t imask_[] = { 12+0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
                           , 8+1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
                           , 4+2, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
                           ,   3, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
static uint8_t omask_[] = {0,4,8,12
                          ,0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
                          ,0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
                          ,0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
#define imask (*(__m128i*)imask_)
#define omask (*(__m128i*)omask_)
    /* ... */
__m128 msa = _mm_set1_epi32(sa<<8);
__m128 srgb = _mm_setr_epi32(sb,sg,sr,0);
__m128 drgb = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_set1_epi32(DC),imask);
__m128 r2 = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_mulhi_epu16(_mm_sub_epi16(drgb,srgb), msa), srgb);
DC = _mm_extract_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi8(r2,omask),0);
```

**UPD:**
I've managed to squeeze a few 2-3 FPS out of that integer SSE code by loading src_color directly into SSE register, where possible, using the __m128 srgb = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_set1_epi32(c),sse_imsk), which is faster than _mm_setr_epi32. Still not a huge improvement, compared to say loop unrolling for 8 pixels, which provided 4-6 FPS.

Comment: Do you need a 32bit multiply? Mostly this sort of thing is done with `pmaddwd` or `pmulhuw`

Comment: Tried it. Still slower than the non-SSE code, despite pmulhuw automagically doing the >>16. It also somewhat complicates computation, `dr-sr` could be negative, so I need signed mul. I also used _mm_set_epi8 to quickly set color bytes to proper slots. I can't really do _mm_set1_epi32(source_rgb), because it is sr,sg,sb,sa are being passed through various recolor lookup tables before blending. SSE don't appear to provide any lookup-table mapping capabilities.

Comment: Just for clarification: `sx` and `dx` are all `uint8`, right? Best provide a [mre] at least of the scalar version of your code. Depending on how you loop through the data, your compiler might be auto-vectorizing already. And do you actually want `(dx-sx)*sa/256+sx` or `(dx-sx)*sa/255+sx` (as in your float implementation)? Also, usually `sa==0` would mean that you fully keep the `d` pixel (in your version this is reversed).

Comment: And if you actually do things like `_mm_setr_epi32(sb,sg,sr,0);` and your compiler is not able to translate this into a clever shuffle, you will lose more time on that than you can save using SIMD (unless these are the same for every pixel and are set once outside the loop).

Comment: Nope. sx and dx are unpacked into int (which is int32_t on x86). I use reversed sa, because it simplifies some formulas and code. I've managed to squeeze a few 2-3 FPS out of SSE by loading src_color directly into SSE register, where possible, using the `__m128 srgb = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_set1_epi32(c),sse_imsk);`, which is faster than `_mm_setr_epi32`. I've also manually unrolled the loop which also gave 4-6 FPS. So I guess loop unrolling should be considered before bothering with SSE. Is there a way to disable compiler auto vectorization for GCC or Clang?

Comment: chtz, yeah, _mm_setr_epi32 was the main perpetrator. Still have to use it in some cases, because SSE can't do table lookup with its registers, while I need it to implement non-linear functions, like brightness and color filter.

Comment: @SmugLispWeenie My question about `sx`, `dx` was more about how they are stored in the image (i.e., I don't think you have a `4*32bit` pixel depth). Show a complete example of how you read source and dest pixels and how you store them again!

Comment: they are stored as 32bit RGBA. I tried using 64bit RGBA, but it was like 2 times slower. In addition 16-bit color component needs 16-bit lookup table to filter, which slows it down further. The example would be too large and complicated, as it uses a macroprocessor to generate all the combinations of blitting modes.

Comment: You should reduce your code to the actual alpha-blending and post it here (having your actual code split into easier functions will help maintaining it anyway. Replace anything not relevant to the question by dummy function calls. It is still not clear to me whether `sr,sg,sb,sa` actually contain 32bit data, or you just store them as such? (If so, why?)

Comment: It would be too much work, and would still depend on the compiler:
https://www.learning2.de/cs/partdiff/
"Clang also supports these intrinsics, but lowers most of them only to the corresponding LLVM IR instructions. Consequently, as optimizations in Clang are performed on the level of the LLVM IR, the produced assembly code diverges from the original code. This implies that the intrinsics are not as useful as for compilers like GCC, and the programs produced by Clang are in many cases slower than GCC-compiled programs if intrinsics are employed."

Comment: Is your data properly aligned to be placed into / read from xmm registers? From your snippets imask and omask are not. It may be that you are loosing speed due unaligned reads.

Comment: I've added  __attribute__ ((aligned(16))), but it had no effect. Guess Clang infers that if something is passed to SSE intrinsic, it should be aligned. These are global variables, so there should be no problem aligning them, compared to stack ones. Aligning stack variables is a notoriously difficult task. The color DWRODs themselves are 32-bit, so cannot be aligned. sr,sg,sb,sa, while 128-bit, cannot be aligned, either, because they are stack vars. I haven't tried GCC, because GCC's ABI is incompatible with Clang, and crashes Clang code on load. I'm using Clang for my Lisp scripting.

Comment: You should just write `__m128i const imask = _mm_setr_epi8(...)` and let the compiler decide whether to store this in a register, in the data segment or on the stack. _Maybe_ with your macro notation the compiler is already smart enough to load it into a register once -- **but that is impossible to tell, if you are not providing a [mre]!**

Comment: Compiler (Clang) says that _mm_setr_epi8 is not constant, so it cant be assigned to global variables.

Comment: No problem at all, if you compile with C++: https://godbolt.org/z/DYnm14. And if you compile with C (which you never mentioned ...), just make it a function-local constant: https://godbolt.org/z/u5vyL3

Comment: Yeah. I'm compiling it as C, because the code is called from higher level language, and C has simple and stable ABI, compared to C++, which mangles stuff. C++ has special init function, that constructs the objects.

Comment: You need to show us the inner loop (at least), and write it without `_mm_setr_epi32` but using `_mm_loadu_si128` instead. Besides, `_mm_mullo_epi16` should be enough for 8-bit multiplication.

Comment: Other fundamental though about writing in SSE: constructions like 
_mm_setr_epi32(sb,sg,sr,sa) inside inner loop should never exist. In other words you should never construct contents of xmm register from smaller parts. To gain speed - you need to deal with xmm registers only, not by constructing them from either bytes, shorts or dwords, nor loading from unaligned memory. Prepare your data correctly, allocate memory for bitmaps under aligned address, align each bitmap scanline to 16 byte etc, then data will fit into sse properly.

Comment: I know that moving from general registers is slow, but, as I mentioned above, SSE don't support using register content as memory addresses. Only latest AVX have limited support for that.